# Puppeteer fails to post

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to intercept a request, add some headers, change the method to post and pass some postData but seems to fail with the method that still being GET, also postData is undefined.

There is my code:

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on('request', interceptedRequest => {
  var overrides;
  if (interceptedRequest.url() === 'https://www.example.com/') {
    console.dir(querystring.stringify(query));
    let headers = interceptedRequest.headers();
    headers['host'] = 'example.com/';
    headers['origin'] = 'https://www.example.com/';
    headers['referer'] = 'https://www.example.com/test';
    headers['x-requested-with'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
    headers['accept'] = 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01';
    headers['accept-encoding'] = 'gzip, deflate, br';
    headers['content-type'] = 'application/json; charset=UTF-8';
    overrides = {
      'method': 'POST',
      'postData': querystring.stringify(query),
      'headers': headers
    };
  }
  interceptedRequest.continue(overrides);
});
```

Then if I intercept the response:

```
...
 _resourceType: 'document',
 _method: 'GET',
 _postData: undefined,
 _headers:
  { 'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent':
     'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/72.0.3582.0 Safari/537.36',
    host: 'example.com',
    origin: 'https://www.example.com/',
    referer: 'https://www.example.com/test',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    accept: 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' }
  ...
```

Thanks